# Why am I getting arbirary exceptions when using Subsonic 3

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I have a few questions regarding Subsonic 3:

- Does anyone use it in their projects?
- Why do I keep on getting primary key exceptions when accessing tables?
- Why do I seem to be getting arbitrary null reference exceptions when using subsonic?

Comment: I edited the question so its less argumentative. phrasing it in the tone of "this is crap, I'm not going to use it anymore" is just going to make people feel bad. Keep in mind, people like the Author of subsonic frequent stack overflow. See the above comment.

Comment: Also, please elaborate on these arbitrary null ref exceptions

Comment: Well I just used the T4 templates that came with the example till now the issues are gone. By the way, I did have primary keys in my tables, but when trying to get objects in code I would get an exception telling me to add a subsonic attribute to the primary key property, before I was using the T4 templates found in SubSonic 3 Final\T4 Templates\ActiveRecord

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not using primary keys, the activerecord templates aren't going to work for you. Not a bug - it's like complaining that your car doesn't drive sideways. It's not in the feature list.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, we're using it (one project uses [ActiceRecord](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_ActiveRecord) and the other [SimpleRepository](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_SimpleRepository)) and it is working great. You might want to visit the [SubSonic Docs](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Main_Page) and walkthrough a couple of the demos before to dismiss it as an option. I have a feeling learning some of the SubSonic fundementals would really help you out.